# How can I run my published dotnet WebAssembly project (not hosted) ? May be dotnet <MyApp>.dll ? It's not working

Tags: .net, blazor-webassembly

I build Visual Studio Blazor WebAssembly project (not hosted).

If I start "dotnet run" in project folder, then my app working fine.

Then I make it published. In folder "publish" I see folder wwwroot and inside _framework with .dll.
If I run "dotnet.exe .\wwwroot_framework\BlazorWANothosted.dll" then error:

A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\APP\DOTNET\BlazorWANothosted\bin\Release\net7.0\browser-wasm\publish\wwwroot_framework'.                             Failed to run as a self-contained app.                                                                                    - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\APP\DOTNET\BlazorWANothosted\bin\Release\net7.0\browser-wasm\publish\wwwroot_framework\BlazorWANothosted.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.                                  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\APP\DOTNET\BlazorWANothosted\bin\Release\net7.0\browser-wasm\publish\wwwroot_framework\BlazorWANothosted.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.

Where that "hostpolicy.dll"  ?

Comment: `dotnet publish -c Release` where we can create folder inside bin

Comment: same results errors

Comment: I am actually have to start dotnet.exe .\wwwroot_framework\BlazorWANothosted.dll  ?

Comment: You need a web server to host the application - there are many. [`dotnet serve`](https://github.com/natemcmaster/dotnet-serve#dotnet-serve) is one I like for testing

Comment: But how I can start Kestrel for my app ?